# Javascript/Typescript: Get index of an JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I've got an JSON object which looks like this:

```
const object = [
    {
        name: 'first',
        color: 'red',
        structure: 
        {
            height: 50,
            width: 20
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'second',
        color: 'blue',
        structure: 
        {
            height: 10,
            width: 60
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'third',
        color: 'green',
        structure: 
        {
            height: 80,
            width: 40
        }
    }
];
```

I'd now like to find the index of the JSON Object with 'name: second' how do I do this without looping with javscript/typescript and without jQuery? If I want the index of 'name: second' the result should be '1'.

Comment: Not really a duplicate tho, as the OP is asking for the index of the object satisfying that condition.

Comment: OP, not only is that not a JSON object, it's not even a valid JS object.

Comment: Also, the index for `name === 'second'` would be 1, not 2.

Comment: now it should match.

Comment: It is an valid object because I'm working with objects like those but I've got a case, where I need the index of some fields.

Comment: `name: second` is not valid unless `second` is the name of a variable. You probably mean `name: 'second'`.

Comment: I've put `name: 'second'` in quotation marks for a better understanding but it seems like I achieved the opposite :/